# Numpy Linespace Not Working

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

So I interpolated from data files and got a function. Later, I used linspace to create x values which I would then plug in to the function. However, when I did so, the x-range expanded to 100. I don't understand why it is doing this. How should I fix this?[image]

```
x = np.loadtxt("/Users/shawn/Desktop/VDFDensityfinalz.dat", unpack = True)
y = np.loadtxt("/Users/shawn/Desktop/VDFDensityfinalshift.dat", unpack = True)
f = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'cubic')
xnew = np.linspace(0.0414, 1.0414,100)
plt.plot(f(xnew))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the `linspace` that's the problem, but your `plot` function that is. If you use
 `plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew))` you will get the graph you want.